# Text overwrites in Ireport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

Whenever I try to run pdf with jasper reports, it overwrites the text in the pdf.
Please help. I'm using ireport 4.0.1.

The parameter and text field definition is given below

```
<parameter name="descriptionOfGoods" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
<textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement x="374" y="381" width="188" height="156"/>
    <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
        <font fontName="Courier New" size="7" isBold="true"/>
        <paragraph lineSpacing="Single" lineSpacingSize="1.0"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{descriptionOfGoods}+"  "]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: `Whenever I try to run pdf with jasper reports, it overwrites the text in the pdf. ` - Can you attach the screenshot?

Comment: Try to not overlap the text fields in JRXML because sometimes its looks ok in JasperRepeort server but overlaps in pdf.